# how to select all class except the clicked element in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, content-management-system, javascript-framework

I have a website developed on Drupal. I use a module called collapsiblock (it is basicly a JQuery plugin) to achieve accordion like effect. It is working fine with me (although it is in Beta). But I want to modify it so that when the user clicks on one item of the accordion the other items will collapsed.

In its current stats, it is working in a way that when the user click on one item, it will check if the item is already collapsed or expanded and it will make the item the opposite. That means if the user clicks on one item it will expand and if he/she clicks on another item it will also expand, but it will not collapse the previously clicked item.

You can see the code below. I know where should I add the code to collapse and how to collapse and expand. My question is: How do I select all the items that have the class '.collapsiblock' except the one that the user has clicked??

Note: the item that has the class '.collapsiblockCollapsed' get collapsed and if this class is removed from the item it get expanded.

```
// $Id: collapsiblock.js,v 1.6 2010/08/18 19:17:37 gagarine Exp $

Drupal.Collapsiblock = Drupal.Collapsiblock || {};

Drupal.behaviors.collapsiblock = function (context) {
  var cookieData = Drupal.Collapsiblock.getCookieData();
  var slidetype = Drupal.settings.collapsiblock.slide_type;
  var defaultState = Drupal.settings.collapsiblock.default_state;
  var slidespeed = parseInt(Drupal.settings.collapsiblock.slide_speed);
  $('div.block:not(.collapsiblock-processed)', context).addClass('collapsiblock-processed').each(function () {
    var id = this.id;
    var titleElt = $(':header:first', this).not($('.content :header',this));
    if (titleElt.size()) {
      titleElt = titleElt[0];
      // Status values: 1 = not collapsible, 2 = collapsible and expanded, 3 = collapsible and collapsed, 4 = always collapsed
      var stat = Drupal.settings.collapsiblock.blocks[this.id] ? Drupal.settings.collapsiblock.blocks[this.id] : defaultState;
      if (stat == 1) {
        return;
      }

      titleElt.target = $(this).find('div.content');
      $(titleElt)
        .addClass('collapsiblock')
        .click(function () {
          var st = Drupal.Collapsiblock.getCookieData();
          if ($(this).is('.collapsiblockCollapsed')) {
            $(this).removeClass('collapsiblockCollapsed');
            if (slidetype == 1) {
              $(this.target).slideDown(slidespeed);
            }
            else {
              $(this.target).animate({height:'show', opacity:'show'}, slidespeed);
            }

            // Don't save cookie data if the block is always collapsed.
            if (stat != 4) {
              st[id] = 1;
            }
          } 
          else {
            $(this).addClass('collapsiblockCollapsed');
            if (slidetype == 1) {
              $(this.target).slideUp(slidespeed);
            }
            else {
              $(this.target).animate({height:'hide', opacity:'hide'}, slidespeed);
            }

            // Don't save cookie data if the block is always collapsed.
            if (stat != 4) {
              st[id] = 0;
            }
          }
          // Stringify the object in JSON format for saving in the cookie.
          var cookieString = '{ ';
          var cookieParts = [];
          $.each(st, function (id, setting) {
            cookieParts[cookieParts.length] = ' "' + id + '": ' + setting;
          });
          cookieString += cookieParts.join(', ') + ' }';
          $.cookie('collapsiblock', cookieString, {path: Drupal.settings.basePath});
        });
      // Leave active blocks uncollapsed. If the block is expanded, do nothing.
      if (stat ==  4 || (cookieData[id] == 0 || (stat == 3 && cookieData[id] == undefined)) && !$(this).find('a.active').size()) {
        $(titleElt).addClass('collapsiblockCollapsed');
        $(titleElt.target).hide();
      }
    }
  });
};

Drupal.Collapsiblock.getCookieData = function () {
  var cookieString = $.cookie('collapsiblock');
  return cookieString ? Drupal.parseJson(cookieString) : {};
};
```

### **UPDATE:**

Problem has been solved by adding the following code:

```
$('.collapsiblock').not(this).each(function(){
                $(this).addClass('collapsiblockCollapsed');
                $(this.target).animate({height:'hide', opacity:'hide'}, slidespeed);
             });
```

just above the following line:

```
$(this).removeClass('collapsiblockCollapsed');
```

Answer (score 204, accepted):

Use the [`not`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) selector.

Example:

```
$('.collapsiblock').click(function(){
     $('.collapsiblock').not(this).each(function(){
         $(this).slideUp();
     });
     $(this).slideDown();
})
```

Comment: Perfect for making radio-ish checkboxes!

Comment: Vanilla please! :D

Comment: No need to use `.each()` -- `$('.collapsiblock').not(this).slideUp()` should work just fine.

Answer (score 10):

> Try this,This is a better way because if you use each function it will load and in the future when you have more than a thousand div it will take a long time to slide up and slide down.

Example:

```
$('.collapsiblock').click(function(){
   $('.collapsiblock').not(this).slideUp();
   $(this).slideDown();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could keep track of which element has already been clicked with your own jquery  click handler and jquery's data(...) function. Then filter iterating your .collapsiblock items with jquery's filter (...) function to include the items you need.